# How do I use oAuth with spotipy on headless device?

Tags: python, oauth, spotify, spotipy

I want to create a simple app that tracks how many minutes I listen to music on Spotify every day. To my knowledge, I need to use oAuth to receive this data (user-read-currently-playing). I am currently authenticating like this:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token("<username>", scope, client_id="<clientID>", client_secret="<client_secret>", redirect_uri="http://localhost:4466")
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

I know that it works because if I run it on Windows where I have a graphical display, everything is just fine and I can get the redirect Url and the auth code from the browser the login page opens in. Is there any way to get this code on a headless linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:
Instead of using

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token("<username>", scope, client_id="<clientID>", client_secret="<client_secret>", redirect_uri="http://localhost:4466")
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

You can use

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id="id", client_secret="secret", redirect_uri="http://localhost:4466", scope=scope, open_browser=False, ))
```

This achives the same goal. To authenticate in a headless envirement, you can copy the cashed Auth from for example a windows machine to your Linux machine as long as they are both in the folder cmd is opened in.

Comment: The proper way for this would be to use the device authorization grant flow - Spotify does this already for its TV applications, but they seem to block other applications from using it.
I explained how this works and requested that they enable it in [this feature request](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Device-Authorization-Grant-authentication-flow-for-custom/m-p/5485468) - please upvote the idea there if you find it useful.